How related are imaginability and coherence?
There are certain things that seem to contain incoherence by its very definition such as a triangle pentagon. This concept can also not be imagined.
On the other hand, other things may not on the face of it contain obvious semantic incoherence such as a “mind existing outside of time” but is also hard to imagine. It seems to me difficult (if not impossible) to imagine the experience of thoughts occurring, for example, without the passage of time (given that that is our only experience).
As such, how related are these concepts, if they are related?

Side note: it seems to me, also, that one can always escape semantic incoherence by simply redefining terms. For example, one can just redefine what triangular means

You may want to have a look at Wittgenstein's TLP . He talks of logical impossibility and nonsense.

They’re related in the compossible worlds (PW) semantics of intuitionistic and modal logics, and imaginability of primary definite distinct descriptions like 'flying purple pig' means possibility in the first dimension only, but empirical coherence needs the second dimension as allowed by the actual world in a posteriori fashion…

Great question, and I would be interested in adapted versions of this question for other sites (such as writing or worldbuilding ), to see it answered under different lenses. (If you do try to do this, please do read these sites' tour page or help page and adapt the question so it fits and is interesting for the site).

Marvel comic books often feature a "place outside of time", but because they struggle to give sense to this concept, the authors usually simplify it as just a place with its own timeline, whose inhabitants have the power to observe the whole timeline of our real world. Maybe "place in a timeline orthogonal to ours" would be a more accurate description than "place outside of time".

Our limited minds really makes incoherence as a distinct concept not super useful. A set of propositions is either consistent or inconsistent - whether it is "conceivable" or "imagineable" has long been abandoned as a test of coherence.
For me, higher mathematics killed any notion that coherence and imaginability go together. A good example is the Vitali Set or singular functions -- they rigorously have been shown to exist but I'd be lying if I said I had any sort of intuitive/internal visualization of what is going on.
In general, any non-constructive proof of something can avoid being imaginable. That is part of the push from intuitionistic/constructive mathematics to not allow what they see as "logical sleight of hand".
However, not being able to appeal to modus tollens or LEM would really slow things down so most mathematicians just bite the bullet and accept there are lots of things we can define but have almost no intuitive feel for  (or even they go against our intuition).

Interesting points but I guess my question should have been with respect to non mathematical entities then. This is because one cannot imagine an actual infinity or “imaginary” numbers either (funnily enough). But I’m not sure if this is interesting with respect to physical reality, or whether this implies those are coherent concepts in the physical world

@Syed "I’m not sure if this is interesting with respect to physical reality." - Theoretical physicists would take issue with this as their entire profession lies in the applicability of these esoteric things to the physical world. For example, the idea that the electron has "spin" yet it has no physical extension nor internal "structure" is hard if not impossible to imagine -- and  yet, here we have it in the physical world. Similarly for black holes and cosmology -- our mathematical "monsters" appear to be invading the real world

interesting! Perhaps in that case some level of visualization may be made in terms of measurement atleast? For example, it is hard to visualize what charge means in and of itself but it may be easier when one thinks of how a positively or negatively charged particle behaves. With that being said, I’m not a physicist, so we’ve unfortunately came to an area where it is hard for me to comment on certain things @Annika

@Syed — What you describe is called instrumentalism - if you are only describing measurements then you lose claim on the reality of the objects of the theory — the theory is a theory of measurements

Visual imagination is limited by everyday experiences. We cannot picture (imagine) something being both a particle and a wave, yet we accept the wave-particle character of elementary particles.
The fact that no geometrical object can both be a triangle and a pentagon derives from the definitions of those words, and from the fact that three is not equal to five, so is unrelated to what can or can not be imagined. Mathematical proofs are not based on appeals to "imagination"; also, the use of pictorial diagrams to help illustrate the steps in a proof has often led to flawed, invalid proofs. Someone might think it's "obvious" that rectangles are coherent concepts, since we can "imagine" them, but, in fact, the assumption that there are rectangles (Clairault's axiom) is equivalent in neutral geometry to Euclid's parallel postulate. In other words, this is far from "obvious".

Particles and waves are just models that are easy for us to think about, no? So I’m not sure that we can even say for sure that an electron is both our familiar conception of a particle and wave when these are just analogies

If particles are "just" models, then tables and chairs and everything else also are. We can see atoms and molecules. We can measure particles. If they're "just models", I guess you won't mind undergoing high-energy X-rays for long periods of time?

Anyway, the question whether or not they are "just models" is orthogonal to the original question about imagination and coherence... Even if they are just theoretical entities, in our best theories of the structure/interactions of matter, theories that are for all purposes coherent, we can no longer really visualize those entities.

wave particle duality is debated in physics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46237/is-the-wave-particle-duality-a-real-duality

how do we differentiate between whether we can’t imagine an electron vs. just not knowing how to yet? @mudskipper

the second answer says that the duality is a misconception, which is sourced from physicists, not “randoms”. Even the top answer says that they exhibit both wave like and particle like properties depending on the context, which could imply that we can imagine them as each depending on the context @mudskipper

Things that are shown to exist in physical reality seem to be trivially coherent.
Descriptions, on the other hand, are:

Imaginable, at least at the level of the description (because someone has described it),
Carry the "semantic escape clause" issue pointed out (unless you are strict with your definitions), and
Can have levels of coherence with other descriptions and/or themselves.

The main difference in the two examples is that there is little debate on what "triangle" and "pentagon" refer to, and they have very specific definitions that people only break intentionally. "Mind", "time", and "exist" on the other hand...
I will also note that "imaginability" may be described differently by the OP?

A triangular pentagon is not a thing that contains incoherence. A triangular pentagon does not exist at all.
While the two components of this concept are well-defined, your expression "mind existing outside of time" is a meaningless combination of concepts as long as you do not define your concept of mind and your meaning of the expression in quotation marks.
There is no philosophical discussion possible when language is used in such a negligent way.
And your side note to redefine the term triangular seems to me completely remote and an obstacle for further discussion.
I vote to close the question due to lack of clarity.

Incoherent things don’t exist. And whether or not the language of a mind existing outside of time is coherent or meaningless is part of the very point of the question. Replace mind with god and plenty of theists find that meaningful, even if I disagree with them

@Syed If we mean "cosmic time" the God can exist outside of that and still have some sense of time (just not our time). The issues is as Jo states -- we have to be careful of definitions. If people are saying timeless-mind in the sense that it doesn't experience any flow, then indeed it is positing something eternal and unchanging, but the term "mind" is best understood analogously vs literally -- it may feel like a "cop out" to go the analogy route, but I think that is how many religious people keep God talk meaningful.

The burden should be on the proponent of a new proposition to define what it means. If one says God is a mind outside of time and then one points out that the fundamental nature of mind seems to involve time and the theist says “well, that’s just an analogy.”, the theist has still not explained what a mind outside of time even means. @Annika

@Syed - I can’t cover it all here but review this https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/religious-language/

We assume that coherence means consistency.
In formal logic, consistency is -roughly speaking- a property of a set of sentences: we say that a theory (i.e. a set of sentences) is inconsistent when we can deduce from it, using logical laws, a contradiction.
A well-known example from mathematics is so-called Russell's paradox: in a nutshell, it can been derived in naive set theory from the principle that every precisely specified property could be used to determine a set: specifically, the colection of all and only those objects satisfying the specified condition (in symbols: S = { x : condition(x) }).
This principle is known as comprehension principle and has been considered by many logicians and philosophers of the past as a sound logical pronciple.
The principle is clearly imaginable or conceivable, in an obvious sense of imaginability.
IMO the "subtle" issue is about the "deep meaning" of imaginable (conceiveble): maybe it is not the same thing to imagine an object and conceive a concept.
What is "absurd" in a pentagonal triangle? the impossibility of mentally "visualize" it or the inconsistency of the property of a trinagle being pentagonal in the context of other geometrical principles? Basically, the definition of triangle as a plane figure having three sides.
But what about time travel? we can imagine it, and probably it is consistent with current (Relativity) physical laws.
What about quarks and the duality particle-wave? Are we able to imagine them? but they are consistent with current physical laws.
